# get array of arrays by javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel

I try to `get list of options` that has been used by `products` under my categories, **so far i can do that**

> But the problem is if i choose more than one category only options of
>   first category will return.

[DEMO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLzCM.jpg)

## codes

`functions`

```
// load my page
public function create()
{
  $categories = Category::all();
  $statuses = Status::all();
  return view('admin.landings.create', compact('categories', 'statuses'));
}


//get option of categories and return it as json
public function getlandingsubspecifications($id)
{
  $specifications = DB::table('products')
  ->where('category_id', $id)
  ->join('product_subspecification', 'product_subspecification.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
  ->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
  ->groupBy('subspecifications.id')
  ->get();

  return response()->json($specifications);
}
```

`JavaScript`

```
<!-- get subspecifications -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="category_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('admin/getlandingsubspecifications') }}/'+encodeURI(subcategoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            $('select[name="spacefication_id"]').empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                  $('select[name="spacefication_id"]').append(
                        "<option class='form-control' value='"+ value['id'] +"'>"+ value['title'] +"</option>");
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="spacefication_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {{Form::label('category_id', 'Categories')}}
    <select class="form-control tagsselector" name="category_id" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="">Select Categories</option>
     @foreach($categories as $category)
       <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
     @endforeach
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    {{Form::label('spacefication_id', 'Spacefications')}}
    <select class="form-control tagsselector" name="spacefication_id" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="">Select Spacefications</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

## UPDATE

`my network result on selecting categories`

[image: screen1]

Answer (score 0):

Pass array of ids to  [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-wherein) fucntion

```
public function getlandingsubspecifications($arrayOfIds)
{
    $specifications = DB::table('products')
           ->whereIn('category_id',[$arrayOfIds])
        //rest of code
}
```

Comment: still does the same, nothing different.

Comment: are you passing array of categories id ??/

Comment: which part should id `dd` to make sure?

Comment: in the begging of `getlandingsubspecifications` function do `dd($arrayOfIds)`

Comment: no i changed your code to my `$id` i don't think naming is making much different

Comment: make sure you are passing more then one id to the whereIn , alright ?

Comment: oh God, I tell you pass more then one id and  change `where` to `whereIn`

Comment: that is the result of it!

Comment: `where`, `whereIn` with `[]` without `[]` all results are the same as you see in my update. I tried all.

Comment: test like this: `->whereIn('category_id',[1,2,3])` if you have categories with ids of 1,2,3, hardcode it

Comment: that way, when i select categories i have list of options of all of them. and when i remove them their options still there.

Comment: well? any idea?